# How to make gnome-calculator accept comma as thousand separator?

Tags: configuration, locale, gnome-calculator

I want to make gnome-calculator works with an input number that has commas inside as thousands separator, currently, [gnome-calculator auto subtracts all the numbers following the first comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ceOk.png).

My `LC_NUMERIC` config here:

```
decimal_point="."
thousands_sep=""
grouping=-1
numeric-decimal-point-wc=46
numeric-thousands-sep-wc=0
numeric-codeset="UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 1):

GNOME-Calculator reads the <kbd>,</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> as a decimal.  It is something that is hard coded into the app itself.  If you would like that as a feature you will have to file a feature request by `ubuntu-bug gnome-calculator`.

However, the comma can be automatically inserted for you. **Do not press the comma <kbd>,</kbd> as the calculator will assume it is a decimal.**

Click on the Gear and select Preferences.

[image]

Then turn on the Thousands Separators.

[image]

Then when you are typing in the numbers like 10000 the comma will be added automatically.

[image]

Comment: I still get the same result. hic

Comment: @logbasex Do not press the comma.  The calculator assumes that is the decimal.